# randomize words form a sentence in php

Tags: php

We have a exercise where we have 3 input fields, from those input fields there comes a scentance but we need to randomize the words location. And the scentance's cannot be the same I am quite stuck with this one can anyone help me, this is what I got right now :

```php
<?php
    $word1 = $_POST['word1'];
    $word2 = $_POST['word2'];
    $word3 = $_POST['word3'];
    $words = [$word1, $word2, $word3]
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($word1 && $word2 && $word3)){
            echo "Alle woorden invoeren.";
        } else {
            for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
                shuffle($words);
                echo implode(" " ,$words);
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code as text, not an image. Unlike images, text can be easily copied and searched.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "sentences cannot be the same"? How many sentences do you have to output?

Comment: You're close but your var definitions need to be inside the `if(empty` and you can't use `&&` inside the `empty`, use seperate `empty` for each var.

Comment: Alright ill keep in mind to post code instead of images :)

Comment: for example if the words are : Hi I'm Luciferno. It cannot print out I'm Luciferno Hi twice. I need 3 words print out three times in diffrent orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, but your definitions have to be inside the `if(`. And you have to use && for each empty.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $word1 = $_POST['word1'];
        $word2 = $_POST['word2'];
        $word3 = $_POST['word3'];
        $words = [$word1, $word2, $word3];
        if(empty($word1) || empty($word2) || empty($word3))){
            echo "Alle woorden invoeren.";
        } else {
            for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
                shuffle($words);
                echo implode(" " ,$words);
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

If I'm not wrong, this should be what you want.

Comment: @Lucifenroo Accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Also, this doesn't make sure that the 3 are unique.